# Check for number of perfect pairs in array

Tags: c++, arrays, perfect-square

Given an array of A of N integers. A pair of indices (i,j) (i < j) is called a "perfect pair" if the product of elements at these indices is a perfect square. A perfect square is a positive integer which is a product of an integer with itself. Find the number of perfect pairs in A.

I tried solving the question.Initially I kept count of numbers in a map. My approach was that if I had 1 and a perfect square in the array, i would count those. Then I would check for numbers in array like (3,3,3) this will result to 3 pairs which I got from the formula of **(count of number*(count of number - 1))/2**. But this approach is giving wrong ans for certain test cases and I don't know why.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> v(n,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }
    int cnt=0;
    int cnt1=0;
    unordered_map<int,int> count;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        count[v[i]]++;
                // count for 1's
        if(v[i]==1){
            cnt1++;
        }
    }
    for(auto it: count){
        //check how many perfect squares can be formed--> eg(3,3,3,3,3)
        if(it.second!=0){
            int n=it.second;
            cnt+=(n*(n-1))/2;
        }
        //check for pair of 1 and perfect square--> eg(1,16)
        if(it.first!=1){
            int num=sqrt(it.first);
            if(num*num==it.first){
                cnt=cnt+(cnt1*it.second);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<cnt<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger on those cases where it does not give the expected answer?

Comment: `8*2=16=4*4`, hope this helps.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: It is not even about a debugger. The logic you used is faulty, as n. m. could be an AI
 has pointed out. The program has not covered all the cases, so it is impossible to get the correct answer unless you rewrite the whole logic. Get a failed test case, manually calculate the result without writing any code, and compare with the answer. Only after you can get this correct should you start to try to fix your program. Using a debugger when the fundamental logic is faulty is not that helpful.

Comment: As another hint: any pair of perfect squares is also a perfect pair.

Comment: Just a remark `if(it.second!=0)` will always be true ...

Comment: Currently your approach is only counting perfect squares that can be generated from the same number `x` appearing more than once and from pairs `(1,y)` where `y` already is a perfect square. But you also need to consider pairs like `(3,12)` which gives `36 == 6*6` and thus a perfect square too

Comment: @WeijunZhou but a debugger can help step through the code and notice when the expected result starts to differ from the actual results...

Comment: @derpirscher In general case maybe. In this particular case the actual result from the test case is just a single number, for which a debugger really cannot help much until your get the logic right and the issue really becomes a bug in your coding. If on the other hand the answer is a sequence, then it may be helpful. My point is, now that someone has already pointed out the logic is faulty in the comments, OP shouldn't waste any more time on debuggers before he gets his logic correct, only after that should he use a debugger to fix programming issues.

Comment: @WeijunZhou We don't know what testcases OP has tried. Obviously OP has some failed tescases, and those can easily be analysed with the help of a debugger, ie why a pair like `2,8` isn't counted (because there is no code for counting it) ...

Comment: Yeah, this was a question at code drills. This platform doesn't show for which test cases the code's logic fails. I never thought about the test case of 2,8 and therefore came with the faulty logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only count a subset of valid pairs. Let a square be S = N*N, then the valid factorization of a perfect square you count is:

`S = N*N = 1 * (N*N)`

Suppose `S = 4*4 = 16`

Then you only count these circumstances:
`16 = 4*4 = 1*16`

But what about `2*8` which also contributes to the final result? You forgot that and that is the reason why you fail some of the test cases.

Consider an array: `[1, 2, 4, 8]`

there are 2 pairs: [0, 2] and [1, 3], but your algorithm just count 1 pair, which is wrong.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

First of all let's [factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) each array element.

Then notice that any prime factor that occurs an even number of times doesn't matter, so we can throw an even number of occurrences of each prime away. In essence we divide each number by the biggest perfect square we can. For example, instead of the number *48600 = 2<sup>3</sup>×3<sup>5</sup>×5<sup>2</sup>* we use *2×3=6* because we can throw away (= divide the original number by)  *2<sup>2</sup>×3<sup>4</sup>×5<sup>2</sup>*.

After the transformation, each prime factor occurs no more than once in each number. Now notice that we only get perfect squares from products of identical numbers. For a number that occurs *n* times in the array we get *n×(n-1)/2* perfect squares. Finding how many times each number occurs in an array is left as an exercise for the reader.